# Using count to find number of occurrences of a value with a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, count, where-clause

I have this table (this is a short version)

```
item_id    computer_type   operating_system
  1           PC             UNIX
  2           DESKTOP        OSX
  3           LAPTOP         WINDOWS
  4           DESKTOP        UNIX
  5           PC             OSX
  6           PC             WINDOWS
```

How would I use SQL to determine the number of 'desktop' computers in the table that run with 'unix'?

Comment: Doesn't get much easier, please show what have you tried?

Comment: SELECT computer_type, operating_system, count(*)
FROM computers
WHERE computer_type = 'DESKTOP' and operating_system ='UNIX'
GROUP BYcomputer_type, operating_system;

Comment: This is what i thought was the closest, but i only got the column names with no data in the table

Comment: That query looks like it should work (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/297e0d/2).  Are you sure you have that data?  Or what are your expected results?

Comment: I 100% have that data because if I run SELECT * FROM computers i get the table up. But when I run that query i posted earlier I just get the column names 'computer_type' ' operating_system' and 'count(*)' with no data where as i would expect 1 entry with the amount of desktops running Unix

Comment: Im using sql developer by the way, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Did you review the fiddle I provided?  Can you replicate the problem you're having in a different fiddle?  Perhaps you have spaces in the values or other hidden characters such as line breaks.  What if you change your `where` criteria to use `like` instead?  `where computer_type like '%desktop%'`... Or try both `where` criteria independently.  I suspect your issue is with your data.

Comment: What are the data types of your columns? You can use `DESCRIBE computers;` to find out if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(1)
from table
where computer_type = 'DESKTOP'
and operating_system = 'UNIX'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT computer_type,
       operating_system,
       count(*)
FROM   computers
WHERE  computer_type    = 'DESKTOP'
AND    operating_system = 'UNIX'
GROUP BY
       computer_type,
       operating_system;
```

This assumes that the `COMPUTER_TYPE` and `OPERATING_SYSTEM` columns have type `VARCHAR2` (which you can see if you use the `DESCRIBE computers;` command). If they have type `CHAR` then they will be right-padded with space characters and you can use this:

```
SELECT computer_type,
       operating_system,
       count(*)
FROM   computers
WHERE  RTRIM( computer_type )    = 'DESKTOP'
AND    RTRIM( operating_system ) = 'UNIX'
GROUP BY
       computer_type,
       operating_system;
```

Or, you can right pad the string literals out the the appropriate length:

```
SELECT computer_type,
       operating_system,
       count(*)
FROM   computers
WHERE  computer_type    = 'DESKTOP        '
AND    operating_system = 'UNIX           '
GROUP BY
       computer_type,
       operating_system;
```